# Voltage change on Resistor change (TinkerCad)

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have a simple circuit in TinkerCad with a 9V battery and resistor. Every time I alter the resistor, the voltage across it changes.

1 ohm resistor:

[image: 3.6v]

2 ohm resistor:

[image: 5.14v]

3 ohm resistor:

[image: 6v]

The voltage on the resistor should remain constant (9v) regardless of the resistor value. What is the problem?

Comment: You realise a 1 Ohm resistor is going to try and draw 9 Amps from your battery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The battery would only put out a constant voltage if it is ideal. However, real-world batteries are not ideal, and their voltage will sag when you try to draw a lot of current.

This is often modeled using an *internal resistance*, meaning that the battery acts like an ideal voltage source + a resistor:

[image]

Based on your first image (1 ohm resistor, 3.6V), if tinkercad is modeling the battery in this way, it's using an approximately 1.5-ohm resistor. The following schematic shows the actual circuit that tinkercad is likely simulating.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM30a7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the current drawn from the battery is only 3.6 A, rather than the 9A you'd expect from a 1-ohm resistor across an ideal voltage source.

Also note that 9V batteries don't have a lot of capacity, so if you tried this in the real world, the battery would run flat rather quickly, with its voltage rapidly sagging further.

Answer (score 2):

The battery itself has an internal resistance that is part of the circuit.  It is in series with the resistor.

Answer (score 2):

Your simulator is also simulating the parasitic elements of the battery. 9 V batteries have pretty significant ESR.

If you mean to use an ideal 9 V source, use an ideal 9 V source.