# Maintain parallel motor speeds

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have two motors connected in parallel.

When connected to a 9V battery, the motors spin at 269 RPM. However, when I remove one motor, the remaining one speeds up to 289 RPM.

In contrast, when connected to the 5V pin on an Arduino, the motors spin at 170 RPM, and removing one motor does not affect the speed of the remaining one.

How can i achieve the same thing with the 9v battery without the arduino?

9v two motors (269rpm):
[image]

9v one motor (286rpm):
[image]

5v arduino two motors (170rpm):
[image]

5v arduino one motor (**170rpm**):
[image]

Comment: Note that [a 9-volt battery is a particularly unstable power source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/688611/voltage-change-on-resistor-change-tinkercad/); its voltage will vary significantly with load.

Comment: @Hearth I have tested it with all sorts of batteries (1.5v, 3v, 6v) and got the same results

Comment: It will happen with any unregulated power supply, but 9 V batteries are particularly bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Motor speed is proportional to the supplied voltage (with an influence from the load the motor is driving). As you have measured, changing the total current drawn from your 9 V battery changes its output voltage, and hence the speed of the motor. The supply driving the Arduino keeps the voltage constant over the range of currents you are drawing.

You need a regulated voltage supply to your motors. You can buy voltage regulators, and DC-DC power converters. The type you need depends on what voltage battery you run from, and what voltage you need to deliver to the load. Buck (step down) DC-DC converters, and linear voltage regulators, always deliver a lower voltage than they receive, the maximum voltage limited by the dropout voltage required across the regulator. Boost converters can only deliver a higher voltage than they are supplied with. You can also get buck-boost regulators which can deliver both higher and lower voltages than they are supplied with.

Comment: Thank you, is using a regulated voltage supply the regular practice among crcuits for real products?

Comment: Please note that linear voltage regulator are suitable for low current like less than 1A. When used with more current they waste a lot of energy. A Boost converter will also have hard time providing a lot of current at much higher voltage than the supply.

Comment: If you mean commercial products, there is no such a thing as regular practice. Some manufacturer will made things so cheap that's not even funny. I would say they are bad practices and good ones.

Comment: Commercially, if you want to keep two motors going the same speed, or a single motor at a constant speed, you measure the motor speed and control it. I was making the assumption that this was a hobby/learning exercise, and that constant voltage as from an Arduino supply was sufficient for your purposes. As @Hearth says, a PP3 battery is about the worst choice for a motor supply application. Note that I mention that motor load also affects the speed. It can affect the speed down to zero, though generally we run motors at a load of 5% to 10% speed variation.